# What do these ARM assembly lines do?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to answer an assignment question and I'm unsure if I'm correct or not.

The question is:

Briefly explain the purposes of the instructions on lines 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
12 and 13.

My answer:

3 - Loads the (address/value?) of var A, into R1.

4 - Moves the constant MAX into R2.

--

7 - Compares the contents of R2 with the constant 0.

8 - Ends the branch (loop) if R2=0

9 - Load contents of R1 into R4

10- Adds data in R3 with R4, result saved in R3.

11- Adds data in R1 with constant 4, result saved in R1.

12- Subtracts data in R2 with constant 1, result saved in R2.

13- Loop back to start of loop1

```
1. .global _start
2. _start:
3. LDR R1, =A
4. MOV R2, #MAX
5. MOV R3, #0
6. loop:
7. CMP R2, #0
8. BEQ end
9. LDR R4, [R1]
10. ADD R3, R4
11. ADD R1, #4
12. SUB R2, #1
13. B loop
14. end: ...
15. .data
16. .equ MAX, 5
17. A: .rept MAX
18. .word 0x00
19. .endr
```

Comment: If by `9 - Load contents of R1 into R4` you mean content of memory at address R1 (which has been set to address of `A`) then you seem to be correct.

Comment: 3 - unfinished. 9 is wrong (as it uses the same wording as 7) And 13 I don't like either.

Answer (score 1):

I think, all the answers provided by you are correct, except the followings,.

a)

> 3 - Loads the (address/value?) of var A, into R1.

Line 3 will put the memory location of line 17 into R1.

b)

> 8 - Ends the branch (loop) if R2=0

If R2 == 0, then the execution will jump to line 14

c)

> 9 - Load contents of R1 into R4

Load the content of the memory address held by R1 into R4.
e.g. If R1=0x01234567 and memory address 0x01234567 has the value 0x89abcdef
then after executing line 9, R4 will hold the value 0x89abcdef

Comment: `8` isn't wrong in the question; line 14 is the right after the loop so it is a `break` out of the loop like the OP (awkwardly) described.

Comment: Correct peter, in this specific case this will break the loop, in generic sense it will jump to a specific location.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP knows that, even though the rest of it is all just "architectural effect of the instruction without context", not an attempt to reverse-engineer or describe the higher-level behaviour of this loop over an array.  If you want to make your argument, then you need to look at lines 7+8 together.  On its own, 8 branches on the Z flag, regardless of how it was set.  Or at least reword your answer to not claim the OP has 8 *wrong*, that's just confusing for them.  And while you're at it, your example for 9 could point out that R1 holds a pointer to an array element.